# Different permissions for same document library for two different pages?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, permissions, custom-permission-level

Is it possible to have 2 different permissions for the same person, when editing the same document library on the different pages?

**For Example:**

Let's say on TestPage1 and TestPage2 have the same DocumentLibrary. When a user goes to TestPage1, he has edit privilege for the DocumentLibrary webpart. On TestPage2, he has read only privilege for the DocumentLibrary webpart.

This would be useful for allowing all users to see the last approved Major version on TestPage2, but see drafts on TestPage1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it's not possible,** regardless in which page (TestPage1 and TestPage2)  you have hosted the library, the permission will be the same for the same person in this library.

---

**By the way,** the drafts will not be shown for all users until it published as a major version by the user who checked it out. So How will you show the drafts on TestPage1??!

So I suggest creating a view filtered by the document that `Checked out To [ME]` to show the draft based on the current user in your TestPage1.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Based on the permissions of my document library. Users with edit permission are able to see drafts as long as they are checked in. So they can see 1.1, 1.2 etc. I would also like them to be able to see the 1.0 version of the document, but in a nice list view.